# How do I create a unique MatchID for pairs/groups in my MatchIt code?

Tags: r, match, matching, mahalanobis, propensity-score-matching

I've implemented the MatchIt package in R as part of my master thesis research. The code currently matches some sustainable investment firms with non-sustainable investment firms on a ratio of 1:2.

I need to amend my code so that the matches have a Match ID. At the moment the code works well and matches correctly, but I do not know which firms are paired with which controls.

Can anyone suggest an amendment?

I haven't included all of my code as I think thats excessive, but the main lines for the matching step are below:

```
matchData <-
  rbind(treat_firms_1year_prior,
  control_firms_year_int_tx)

matchData <- matchData %>% 
  modify_at(c("country", "region", "strategy", "signatory", "eligible_treat_firm"), as.factor) %>% 
  arrange(investor, dealyear)

matchpanel3 <- MatchIt::matchit(eligible_treat_firm ~ counttotal + dealyear, exact= ~ region + strategy, data = matchData, distance = "mahalanobis", ratio = k+1)
```

Any advice would be very welcome!

Rory

Answer (score 1):

Match ID is stored in the `subclass` component of the `matchit` object or in the `subclass` column of the output of `match.data()`. You don't have to create these yourself.